# SAS (proc sql) count number of records if difference between two date variables greater of 3 years

Tags: count, sas

Uning sas enterprise guide to query database (20 million records in one dataset)
I am trying to use script (proc sql) to get number of records (using variable IncidentID) in table Incidents with Years between Incident_date and recorded_date is greater than 1 year

I am also trying to export all records where incident_date - recorded_date>=3years

The data in table Incidents:

IncidentID    Incident_date   recorded_date
1001          01/01/2016       01/01/2017
1002          10/12/2015       10/12/2015
1005          01/01/2001       01/01/2005
2007          01/01/1999       07/01/2015
999           05/10/2014       10/10/2016

```
PROC SQL; 
    create table incidentdata as
     SELECT incidentID, name, reported_date, Incident_date
      from libraryname.Incidents
      where intck('year',reported_date, incident_date, 'C') >= 1;
       quit;
```

Output required:
1. Count how may cases in the table with recorded_date - incident_date>= 1 year
2. Select all cases with recorded_date - incident_date>= 1 year

This is the code so far:

PLease help

Comment: I know that the following will get me the difference in years but how do i use this in a where clause to get what i want?e.g. years=intck('year','01jan2009'd,'01jan2010'd);

Comment: On this site you are expected to provide sample data, desired output and show us what you already tried. You can also edit your question to add more info rather than commenting on your own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
where intnx('year',date2,-3,'same') >= date1
```

or

```
where intck('year',date1, date2, 'C') >= 3
```

Comment: this does not seem to work as i am not sure what 'C' should on what you said abovePROC SQL;   
      SELECT count(distinct incidentID) AS CNT_incidents, 
             where intck('year',Date 2, Date 1, 'C') >= 3
      FROM Libename..datasetname;
   QUIT;

Comment: It works. `'C'` is just supposed to be `'C'`.  It's an argument of the `intck` function. The problem here is that you lack the most basic SQL knowledge. The `where` clause comes after the `from` clause.

Comment: Also, you need to add a `group by` clause if you want to use an aggregate function like `count` and that's not how you should be counting distinct observations.  If you edit your question with the actual code you're using, someone can probably help you more.